# session closing while using HibernateTemplate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-orm

Consider following code:

```
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {

 private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;
 public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
  this.hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
  }

 public void saveUser(User user) {
 hibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate(user);
 }

 public void deleteUser(User user) {
 hibernateTemplate.delete(user);
 }

}
```

One of the main task of `HibernateTemplate` is to open and close the session transparently.

In above code there are two methods `saveUser()` and `deleteUser()`.I want to ask:

1)Will `HibernateTemplate` create two separate sessions for these two methods and when the closing/flushing of session takes place in this case.

2)Is it same like spring transactions, as in spring, transactions are *adviced* around method calls and opening, closing of session happens at method/transaction boundaries?

Answer (score 0):

Default flush mode is `FlushMode.AUTO`. Look at the links below. I think it will answer your questions.

[http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.9/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateAccessor.html#setFlushMode(int)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.9/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateAccessor.html#setFlushMode%28int%29)

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/FlushMode.html